# Want to show all lines items in result list instead of the last line item

Tags: abap

I have a SELECT query with the aggregate function `group by`. But my program shows only the last line items. I want to show all the line items.

Example of expected result:

```
{"numOfRec":"50",
 "shipmentsDetails":[
   {"orderNum":"1000101730",
    "deliveryOrderNum":"0085099852",
    "prodCode":"OE8002L18",
    "batchCode":"0000029927",
    "qty":"108.000" } , 
   {"orderNum":"1000101730",
    "deliveryOrderNum":"0085099852",
    "prodCode":"OE8407L18",
    "batchCode":"0000029928",
    "qty":"36.000" } , 
   {"orderNum":"1000101730",
    "deliveryOrderNum":"0085099852",
    "prodCode":"SUE9433G1",
    "batchCode":"0000029923",
    "qty":"180.000" }]}
```

Example of actual result (in `i_output`):

```
{"numOfRec":"1",
 "shipmentsDetails":[
   {"orderNum":"1000101760",
    "deliveryOrderNum":"0085099889",
    "prodCode":"UE9101G5",
    "batchCode":"20200101E",
    "qty":"10.000" }]}
```

(although there are many line items, only the last line item is showing)

Here's my code:

```
  IF NOT i_vttk IS INITIAL.
    SELECT tknum
           tpnum
           vbeln
      FROM vttp
      INTO TABLE i_vttp
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN i_vttk
      WHERE tknum = i_vttk-tknum.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      SORT i_vttp BY tknum tpnum.
    ENDIF.

    IF NOT i_vttp is INITIAL.
      LOOP AT i_vttp INTO wa_vttp.
        SELECT vbeln
               matnr
               charg
               SUM( lgmng ) as lgmng
               meins
          FROM lips
          INTO TABLE i_lips
          WHERE vbeln = wa_vttp-vbeln
            AND aedat LE sy-datum
            AND lfimg <> 0
          GROUP BY vbeln matnr charg meins.
        IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
          "APPEND i_lips.
          "CLEAR i_lips.
          SORT i_lips BY vbeln matnr.
        ENDIF.
      ENDLOOP.
    ENDIF.

    LOOP AT i_lips INTO wa_lips.
      READ TABLE i_vttp
            INTO wa_vttp
        WITH KEY vbeln = wa_lips-vbeln.
      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        wa_output-tknum = wa_vttp-tknum.
        wa_output-vbeln = wa_lips-vbeln. " Added Delivery
        wa_output-matnr = wa_lips-matnr.
        wa_output-charg = wa_lips-charg.
        wa_output-lgmng = wa_lips-lgmng.
      ENDIF.
      APPEND wa_output TO i_output.
      CLEAR: wa_vttp, wa_lips, wa_output.
      l_count = l_count + 1.
    ENDLOOP.
```

Note that ideally, I would like to do the following query to sum up the total quantity (field `lgmng`), but ABAP doesn't allow to use `group by` with `for all entries`:

```
SELECT vbeln matnr charg SUM( lgmng ) as lgmng meins 
  FROM lips 
  INTO TABLE i_lips 
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN i_vttp 
  WHERE vbeln = i_vttp-vbeln 
    AND aedat LE sy-datum 
    AND lfimg <> 0
  GROUP BY vbeln matnr charg meins.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Result list: { "numOfRec":"1","shipmentsDetails":[{ "orderNum":"1000101760","deliveryOrderNum":"0085099889","prodCode":"UE9101G5","batchCode":"20200101E","qty":"10.000" }]    } although there are many line items, only the last line item is showing.

Comment: put `vttp` and `lips` table samples into the question, together with the expected result

Comment: SELECT vbeln
             matnr
             charg
             lgmng
             meins
        FROM lips
        INTO TABLE i_lips
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN i_vttp
       WHERE vbeln = i_vttp-vbeln
         AND aedat LE sy-datum
         AND lfimg <> 0.
      IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
        SORT i_lips BY vbeln matnr.
      ENDIF. Sum of total quantity(field lgmng). But abap not allow aggregate function with for all entries. So, I loop the internal table. After looping, show the last line item.

Comment: Expected result:  { "numOfRec":"50","shipmentsDetails":[{ "orderNum":"1000101730","deliveryOrderNum":"0085099852","prodCode":"OE8002L18","batchCode":"0000029927","qty":"108.000" } , { "orderNum":"1000101730","deliveryOrderNum":"0085099852","prodCode":"OE8407L18","batchCode":"0000029928","qty":"36.000" } , { "orderNum":"1000101730","deliveryOrderNum":"0085099852","prodCode":"SUE9433G1","batchCode":"0000029923","qty":"180.000" }

Comment: @HninWaiMarSoe You may edit your own question to improve its clarity; it's better than using only comments. I did it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

1. A select in a loop is generally a bad idea since it increases database accesses(which you really don't want ) . Consider other options like `joins`.
2. The reason why you get only the last line is that in every loop pass( in the loop where you do a select ) the internal table i_lips gets overwritten and hence on exiting the loop, you get only the last selected entries. To solve this you could modify your select query as follows:

   ```
   SELECT vbeln
      matnr
      charg
      SUM( lgmng ) as lgmng
      meins
    FROM lips
    APPENDING TABLE i_lips
    WHERE vbeln = wa_vttp-vbeln
    AND aedat LE sy-datum
    AND lfimg <> 0
    GROUP BY vbeln, matnr, charg, meins.
   ```

Comment: Thank you Dan K. I'm very new in abap. I would like to know one thing more. How can i declare @wa_vttp and @sy-datum? Error message "When escaped, all host variables must be escaped using @."

Comment: I have fixed it in the asnwer, I removed the '@'

Comment: I did as you said. No result comes out.SELECT vbeln
   matnr
   charg
   SUM( lgmng ) as lgmng
   meins
 FROM lips
 APPENDING TABLE i_lips
 WHERE vbeln = wa_vttp-vbeln
 AND aedat LE sy-datum
 AND lfimg <> 0
 GROUP BY vbeln matnr charg meins.  Result :  { "numOfRec":"0","shipmentsDetails":[]    }

Comment: SELECT vbeln
   matnr
   charg
   SUM( lgmng ) as lgmng
   meins
 FROM lips
 APPENDING TABLE i_lips
 WHERE vbeln = i_vttp-vbeln
 AND aedat LE sy-datum
 AND lfimg <> 0
 GROUP BY vbeln matnr charg meins. When try with i_vttp-vbeln show error message "Field "I_VTTP-VBELN" is unknown."

Comment: it should work with `wa_vttp` , put a break point and debug to make sure your records get seleted into the table i_lips.

Comment: SELECT vbeln
             matnr
             charg
             lgmng
             meins
        FROM lips
        INTO TABLE i_lips
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN i_vttp
       WHERE vbeln = i_vttp-vbeln
         AND aedat LE sy-datum
         AND lfimg <> 0.
      IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
        SORT i_lips BY vbeln matnr.
      ENDIF. Work well with this code. But can't aggregate lgmng field because of for all entries.

Comment: Replace For all entries with a join between tables vttp and lips

Comment: Or if your netweaver is 7.5 or higher, there is a group by statement for internal tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216706/discussion-between-hnin-wai-mar-soe-and-dan-k).

Comment: @HninWaiMarSoe Although you say that the corrected program doesn't work as intended, I think that Dan K has answered your question (use of `appending` instead of `into`). I suggest that you vote and mark Dan K answer as Accepted if it answers the actual question. For the rest, it's worth a new question or if you want some general help about your code, I suggest that you go to sites like [SCN](https://answers.sap.com) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abap).

Comment: Thank you Dan. K. This issue is resolved. I did as you said.

Comment: That took long :-))